# Find all values a and b that make this function continuous everywhere.

Tags: calculus

Need a little help getting started here! Thanks =)

$f(x)=\begin{cases}
ax^2 − 3x+5 &\text{if }x < 2\\
b+2a &\text{if } x=2\\
x+b^2 &\text{if } x ≥ 2\end{cases}$

Comment: just a tiny remark: in general you have for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ two definitions at $x=2$: $f\left(2\right)=b+2a$ and since $2\geq 2$ you also have $f\left(2\right)=x+b^2$. So "$x\geq2$" should be replaced by "$x>2$". But that is of minor importance since everything is clear from the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that all three expressions have the same value at $x = 2$; that is, that

$$
a(2)^2-3(2)+5 = 4a-1 = b+2a = 2+b^2
$$

Is that enough to get you started?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the definition of what it means for a function to be continuous at a point:

$$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$$

More specifically, you want to make sure it's continuous at $x=2$.

$$\lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = f(2)$$

But since $f(x)$ is defined by two different parts of your piecewise function to the left and the right of $x=2$, you actually want to use both one sided limits.

$$\lim_{x \to 2^{-}} ax^2 - 3x +5 = b+2a$$
$$\lim_{x \to 2^{+}} x+b^2 = b+2a$$

Simplify those and you'll end up with a system of equations containing $a$ and $b$.  Solving that system would give you the answer.

Here's a link to a website that works through a similar problem, but it's much more detailed in the explanation and why it works:

https://jakesmathlessons.com/limits/solution-find-the-values-of-a-and-b-that-make-f-continuous-everywhere/